# Weblogic JMX error IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0

Tags: java, weblogic, wildfly, rmi, jmx

I have a web service deployed on Wildfly 10.1 which tries to create a connection with the Weblogic connector using RMI. 
But I get the following error :

> ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-13) UT005023: Exception handling request to /ws/sam/test-jmx: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.io.IOException: **Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]**

I have the following code :

```
String protocol = "rmi";
String jndiroot = "/jndi/iiop://" + hostname + ":" + port + "/";
String mserver = "weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime";
JMXServiceURL serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL(protocol, hostname,
            port, jndiroot + mserver);
Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
h.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, wlUsername);
h.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, wlPassword);
JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, h);
```

Do you have an idea what this error means ?

I've tried to do a simple Java client with the same code and it works. But deployed on Wildfly I have the error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because MQ entry JNDI name not configured in WAS like jndiName="jms/SomeMQName"